# add select query result from tableA as a new column in tableB

Tags: mysql, amazon-athena

I am creating a new table from joining two tables through below query:

```
select a.name, a.number, b.id, b.sub_num
    from tableA a left join
         tableB b
         on a.number = concat(id,'-',Cast(sub_num as varchar);
```

Here, I want to add a `new column` into the new table which is select query result on tableA.

The table data would be something like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9TdF.png)

I am trying to use below query which is not correct as it is giving me multiple rows. I need sum of dext_number for condition dext_id = 17501 and group by of name and number columns.

```
select a.name, a.number, b.id, b.sub_num, 
   (select sum(dext_number) from tableA where dext_id = 17501 group by name, number) as newcol 
     from tableA a left join tableB b 
  on a.number = concat(id,'-',Cast(sub_num as varchar);
```

What is the best way to add this column here?

Comment: Please enter your sample data as well as the desired output

Comment: is it related to MySQL or Athena ?

Comment: @AmitVerma: Athena

Comment: Since internal query is grouped on name and number and returning multiple rows. It means name or number is different and due to this query is returning multiple rows. TO avoid this you should provide name and number also to get single cell.

Comment: @MeysamAsadi it didn't work with limit or top.

Comment: @SriVidhyaPavani  I changed the code. In the subquery you can not use Group by instead of Window function.

Comment: @MeysamAsadi Thanks for the update. It did work with limit 1. But i am changing the question now.Please check and let me know the correct correct query. Thanks

Comment: @AmitVerma: Thanks for the update. I am changing the question. Please check and help :)

Answer (score 0):

use following query

```
select a.name, a.number, b.id, b.sub_num, (select sum(dext_number) over(partition by name, number) from tableA 
where dext_id = 'xyz' limit 1) as newcol 
from tableA a 
left join tableB b on a.number = concat(id,'-',Cast(sub_num as varchar);
```

If you want the exact output of the query image, use the following query

```
select L.name,L.number,L.dext_id,L.dext_number,
  case when L.num > 1 then newcol
  else NULL
  end as newcol
from
(select *,
  count(dext_number) over(partition by name, number) as num,
  sum(dext_number) over(partition by name, number) as newcol
  from tableA) L left join tableA R on L.dext_id = R.dext_id and L.name= R.name and L.number = R.number and L.dext_number = R.dext_number
```

And the combination of the first query with tableB will be as follows

```
select a.name, a.number, b.id, b.sub_num, (select
  case when L.num > 1 then newcol
  else NULL
  end as newcol
from
(select *,
  count(dext_number) over(partition by name, number) as num,
  sum(dext_number) over(partition by name, number) as newcol
  from Test) L left join Test R on L.dext_id = R.dext_id and L.name= R.name and L.number = R.number and L.dext_number = R.dext_number limit 1) as newcol 
from tableA a 
left join tableB b on a.number = concat(id,'-',Cast(sub_num as varchar);
```

Comment: Does Athena or MySQL  support TOP keyword ?

Comment: You can use limit instead of top.

Comment: @MeysamAsadi: In the place of Test i added tableA and ran the query. The newcol has all null values.

Comment: @SriVidhya Pavani I do not have tableB data. I can not take the test. But I tested the tableA data in the image. I do not have tableB data. I can not take the test. But I tested the tableA data in the image. Enter the data in TableB to get tested.